# Problem using Huggingface imagenet-1k dataset in Keras / Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, huggingface-datasets

I'm having a problem using the imagenet-1k dataset from Huggingface with a Keras model. I'm just experimenting with simple models, but am stuck trying to get the dataset to work with the model fit function.

Here is how I load the dataset:

```
ds = load_dataset('imagenet-1k')  # loads a DatasetDict
ds_train = ds['train']  # get a Dataset
ds_train.set_format(type='tensorflow', columns=['image'])  # convert to tf tensor
ds_val = ds['validation']  # get a Dataset
ds_val.set_format(type='tensorflow', columns=['image'])  # convert to tf tensor
```

Here is the fit invocation:

```
# train the autoencoder
autoencoder.fit(ds_train, ds_train,
                epochs=10,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(ds_val, ds_val))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>, <class 'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>
```

When I inspect one of the elements of the datasets it looks like a tf.Tensor, so I don't understand why it can't be passed directly. None of the examples or docs I can find make it clear how to do this. Huggingface [examples](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.11.0/en/use_with_tensorflow) for images produce the same format that I'm getting, but apparently there is a step I'm missing before it can be used with model.fit()

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the dataset to a format the model can read. One option would be to have a TensorFlow dataset where each example is a tuple `(image, label)`.

You can convert the Hugging Face dataset to a TensorFlow dataset with the method `to_tf_dataset()` such as this:

`ds_train = ds["train"].to_tf_dataset(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)`

This will return a dictionary per example `{"image": tf.Tensor(image), "label": tf.Tensor(label)}`. You can apply an additional function to map the dataset:

```py
def format_dataset(example):
    image = example["image"]
    label = example["label"]
    return (image, label)

ds_train = ds_train.map(format_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

This way you will have a tuple `(image, label)` per example, where both image and label are `tf.Tensor()`.